# How can I match two sets of factor levels in a new data frame?

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a large data frame and I want to export a new data frame that contains summary statistics of the first based on the id column.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123) 
id = rep(c(letters[1:5]), 2)
species = c("dog","dog","cat","cat","bird","bird","cat","cat","bee","bee")
study = rep("UK",10)
freq = rpois(10, lambda=12)
df1 <- data.frame(id,species, freq,study)
df1$id<-sort(df1$id)
df1

df2 <- df1 %>% group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(meanFreq= mean(freq),minFreq=min(freq))
df2
```

I want to keep the species name in the new data frame with the summary statistics. But if I merge by id I get redundant rows. I should only have one row per id but with the species name appended.

```
df3<-merge(df2,df1,by = "id")
```

This is what it should look like but my real data is messier than this neat set up here:

```
df4 = df3[seq(1, nrow(df3), 2), ]
df4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the summarised output ('df2') we can join with the `distinct` rows of the selected columns of original data

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% 
    left_join(df1 %>% 
                distinct(id, species, study), by = 'id')
# A tibble: 5 x 5
#  id    meanFreq minFreq species study
#  <fct>    <dbl>   <dbl> <fct>   <fct>
#1 a         10.5      10 dog     UK   
#2 b         14.5      12 cat     UK   
#3 c         14.5      12 bird    UK   
#4 d         10         7 cat     UK   
#5 e         11         6 bee     UK
```

---

Or use the same logic with the `base R`

```
merge(df2,unique(df1[c(1:2, 4)]),by = "id", all.x = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Time for `mutate` followed by `distinct`:

```
df1 %>% group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(meanFreq = mean(freq), minFreq = min(freq)) %>%
  distinct(id, .keep_all = T)
```

Now actually there are two possibilities: either `id` and `species` are essentially the same in your `df`, one is just a label for the other, or the same id can have several species.

If the latter is the case, you will need to replace the last line with `distinct(id, species, .keep_all = T)`.

This would get you:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   id [5]
  id    species  freq study meanFreq minFreq
  <fct> <fct>   <int> <fct>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1 a     dog        10 UK        10.5      10
2 b     cat        17 UK        14.5      12
3 c     bird       12 UK        14.5      12
4 d     cat        13 UK        10         7
5 e     bee         6 UK        11         6
```

If your only goal is to keep the `species` & they are indeed the same as `id`, you could also just include it in the `group_by`:

```
df1 %>% group_by(id, species) %>%
      summarise(meanFreq = mean(freq), minFreq = min(freq))
```

This would then remove `study` and `freq` - if you have the need to keep them, you can again replace `summarise` with `mutate` and then `distinct` with `.keep_all = T` argument.